# How to open an embedded word document (OLE object) in XL, add data to this word document and save it on the desktop?

Tags: excel, ms-word, ole, save-as

I am trying to save data coming from XL sheet1 to a word document (embedded in this XL file on sheet1) and save this document on my desktop. The word document is only 8 pages. I would like to save behind the scene, if possible. See Code below.
It is working sometime, but got also often some error:

- First, I am declaring twice wdApp, which is maybe not a good way to code
- I need a MsgBox to avoid the following error message: 'Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action', often followed by error 1004.
- I got sometime, not always the error 1004 on wdObj.Activate
- I got another error if the word document I want to save is already on my desktop (I admit, I didn't work on that yet), probably need to investigate the Save and Close method.
- You will notice also I am saving first the word document with data coming from the XL file.

In other word, my code is not great. If you have any advice, please let me know.

```
' SAVE THE TEMPLATE ON THE DESKTOP
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' Filename
strFileName = GetDesktop & "\METPR" & Sheet1.Cells(13, 10).Value & "rev" & Sheet1.Cells(13, 12).Value & ".docx"
' WORD object
Dim wdApp As Object
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
' Initialisation
Dim wdObj As Object
Set wdObj = Sheet1.OLEObjects("T_Conv")
' Activation
wdObj.Activate
' Save the new Document
wdApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs (strFileName)
' End of objects
wdApp.Application.Quit
Set wdObj = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing
' Temporisation to avoid error 1004 !
MsgBox ("The Word Document METPR" & Sheet1.Cells(13, 10).Value & "rev" & Sheet1.Cells(13, 12).Value & " has been saved on your Desktop.")
' OPEN THE TEMPLATE AND LOAD DATA
' WORD object
Dim wdApp2 As Object
Set wdApp2 = CreateObject("Word.Application")
' Initialisation
Dim wdObj2 As Word.Document
Set wdObj2 = wdApp2.Documents.Open(strFileName)
' Activation
wdObj2.Activate
'------------------------------------------------------------
' Fill the document WORD with Data extracted from this XL file
'------------------------------------------------------------
' Save the new Document
wdApp2.ActiveDocument.Save
' End of objects
wdApp2.Application.Quit
Set wdObj2 = Nothing
Set wdApp2 = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Thanks

Comment: Just as an observation, I have seen several answers/comments on Stackoverflow that offer coding solutions to this problem, but I just don't believe that any of them actually works reliably, and by that I mean "in any old Windows environment that you might be operating in". I could get your code, or similar code to work...sometimes, but rarely more than once. I just wonder whether you might be better off storing your "starting point" Word document in some other way.

Comment: I am working with Window 11. I was thinking a bit the same way, but I really like to have the word documents embedded as it is easy to move the XL file for the users. Maybe, if I use 2 separate buttons to do the task that will help: one for loading the word document to the desktop and one for transferring the data. On top of that I struggle sometime with various VBA works I did as we are working more with SharePoint and new issues appears.

Comment: I don't know Excel well, but I think you could probably store a word document, saved in the .xml format, in an Excel Custom XML part. If so, then you could access the part, save the content to disk (you wouldn't need Word to do that) then automate Word to open it, insert your Excel data, and Save or SaveAs.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, I haven't personally found a reliable way to automate Word to save the embedding. The Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65899857/how-to-open-a-word-object-that-is-embedded-in-an-excel-file/65908049#65908049) *may* work for you, but it "works once then fails" here.

Rather than embed the document in the traditional way, you could save it in .xml format (not the Microsoft Word 2003), then store it in your workbook as a Custom XML Part. Then extract it from the Part and save it as an XML file which you should be able to open via Word and automate in the usual way. For example,

```
Option Explicit
Const theSourceWordXmlFullName As String = "c:\test\mytestdoc1.xml"
Const theTargetWordXmlFullName As String = "c:\test\mytestdoct.xml"
Const theTargetWordDocxFullName As String = "c:\test\mytestdoct.docx"
' This is the URI used in a Word document stored as a Flat Opc .xml 
Const theURI As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage"

Sub recreateAndPopulateXMLPart()
' This stores the Word .xml file in the active workbook
' I.e. you should only need to do it once.
Dim cxp As Office.CustomXMLPart
Dim cxps As Office.CustomXMLParts
Dim i As Long
Dim x As String
Debug.Print theURI
With ActiveWorkbook
  ' find any existing cxps with the namespace and delete them
  Set cxps = .CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace(theURI)
  For i = cxps.Count To 1 Step -1
    cxps(i).Delete
  Next
  
  ' create a new one
  Set cxp = .CustomXMLParts.Add
  
  ' read the Word Flat OPC .xml document and insert it  
  cxp.Load theSourceWordXmlFullName

End With
End Sub


Sub saveWordDoc()
' This saves the .xml
Dim cxps As Office.CustomXMLParts
Dim fso As Object 'Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim ts As Object 'Scripting.TextStream

Dim x As String

With ActiveWorkbook
  Set cxps = .CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace(theURI)
  If cxps.Count > 0 Then
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    ' CreateTextFile(path,overwrite,unicode). If you don't
    ' specify True for Unicode, the Write will fail
    Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile(theTargetWordXmlFullName, True, True)
    ts.Write cxps(1).XML
    ts.Close
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Call openAndAutomate
  End If
End With
End Sub

Sub openAndAutomate()
Dim saveConfirm As Boolean
' Or use late binding, but ensure you use the correct values
' for 
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
On Error GoTo finish
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
saveConfirm = wdApp.Options.ConfirmConversions
wdApp.Options.ConfirmConversions = False
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(theTargetWordXmlFullName)
wdDoc.Content.Text = "I modified the text"
wdDoc.SaveAs2 theTargetWordDocxFullName, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault ' or 16,(late binding)
finish:
If Not (wdDoc Is Nothing) Then
  wdDoc.Close WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges ' or 0 (late binding)
  Set wdDoc = Nothing
End If
If Not (wdApp Is Nothing) Then
  wdApp.Options.ConfirmConversions = saveConfirm
  wdApp.Quit
  Set wdApp = Nothing
End If
End Sub
```